# Identify a group given by a list of generators and relations

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I am looking at a matrix group ($3 \times 3$ matrices) with the following set of generators and relations:

$$\Gamma = \langle A,B,C \space | \space  A^2 = B^2 = C^2=I, \space AC=CA\rangle$$

What group is this?

$\textit{Work so far}:$

Since $AC=CA$ and $A$ and $C$ are both self-inverse, then $\langle A,C\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2 \cong K_4$ (Klein-4 group). $\langle A,B\rangle$ and $\langle B,C\rangle$ are infinite, so are (I think) isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_2 \star \mathbb{Z}_2$ (free group or free product). Those are some subgroups, but how can we identify/describe the full group?

Comment: What about $\left(\mathbb{Z}_2\times\mathbb{Z}_2\right)\star\mathbb{Z}_2$?

Comment: You're saying $(\mathbb{Z}_2 \times \mathbb{Z}_2) \star \mathbb{Z}_2$ is the whole group?

Comment: Yes that is correct! Incidentally, saying that $G$ is a matrix group is irrelevant and distracting. The question that you asked is about a group defined by a finite presentation, not a matrix group.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Can I ask you what do you mean by the $\star$ operation ?

Comment: @JeanMarie: the free product.

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Thanks. I should have read more attentively what the OP has written...

Comment: Ok, got it. Thank you